# How to replace entire html?

Tags: jquery

I try to do something like that:

```
function loadurl(url)
    $.get(url, function(msg) {
        $('html').html(msg);
        }
    );
}
```

but browser no load *.js and *.css files from head section. How to do it?

Comment: If you are replacing the *entire* HTML document, why are you not just changing the location to the new url -- why are you using AJAX?

Comment: You're asking how to delete everything on the page? I've done 90% canvas work, but I recall that document.write in Javascript erased the whole page. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: is your goal to have the url stay the same (www.mysite.com) but have everything on the page change once a link is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should you be using `body` instead of `html`. Surely it is better just to load another page.

Comment: "It _is_ better to load a new page" (in this case).

Comment: If you insert a `head` section into a `body` section, it will be ignored as well. This will not solve the OPs problem and load JS or CSS from the `head`. Actually I think, jQuery is doing some pre-processing on the HTML string and only keeps the content of the `body`.